# Keeping bounds when applying equation to whole column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

```
IF(MAX(A1:A3)>MAX(A5:A1298),MAX(A1:A3)+1,MAX(A5:A1298)+1)
```

This equation i wrote basically checks the largest number in the `A:A` (other than itself) and adds 1 to it and places it in `A4`. I want to apply this equation to the whole column. I know it may not seem logical, and that it is a circular equation, but i have my reasons for doing this. The problem is, when i click on that black dot on the bottom right of the cell to apply the equation to the whole column, the bounds change. It begins to start from `A2` at cell `A5`, and from `A3` at cell `A6`.

I want to create bounds for this, so that each cell begins searching for the maximum value from `A1:A1298`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(MAX($A$1:A3)>MAX(A5:$A$1298),MAX($A$1:A3)+1,MAX(A5:$A$1298)+1)
```

Put that in A4 then copy down.  is that what you meant by keeping bounds?  $ keeps the row or column reference from changing as a cell is copied to another location.